# regular expression making browser unresponsive

Tags: regex, browser

I am using this regular expression to set system name. But if length is 30 and I enter a '.' then browser becomes unresponsive. Can any one please point out anything wrong with this regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/
```

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: you could use `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)$`, not exactly the same but has better performance

Comment: Have you ever heard somthing about [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)? I bet this is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the catastrophic backtracking. The point is the you have an optional pattern `[\.\-]?` and that makes the regex engine perform too many backtracking steps to understand that there is no match (when the string is long and the last non-matching char is `.` or `-`). Here is [a demo of a short string causing the issue](https://regex101.com/r/hU8fD6/1).

You just need to remove the `?` quantifier in this case:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/
```

Here is [the demo showing how the regex fails gracefully](https://regex101.com/r/hU8fD6/2).

The point is that each subsequent subpattern shouldn't match the same text.

Also, `.` and `-` do not have to be escaped in the `[.-]`.

If you are not using the captured value, replace `(` with `(?:` to make the group non-capturing.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, not sure what you mean by capture/non-capture value but removing '?' like you mentioned solved the problem.

Comment: When you place `(...)` inside the pattern, you can later access the captured value via correspondence backreference/index. Say, you have [`[0-9]+([A-Za-z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/oZ2wX7/1). If you match `115ABB`, `115` will get matched, and `ABB` will be matched and captured into Group 1. You can replace the whole match with the captured value (as in demo), or you may access with `[1]`: `"115ABB".match(/[0-9]+([A-Za-z]+)/)[1]` to get `ABB` only, not `115ABB`.